# Behaviour of $\int_0^{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}\exp(x\cos(\sqrt{t}))dt$

Tags: integration, analysis, asymptotics

I want to analyze the behaviour of $\int_0^{\frac{\pi^2}{4}}\exp(x\cos(\sqrt{t}))dt$, i.e I want to show it behaves like $e^x(\frac{2}{x}+\frac{2}{3x^2}+...)$ as $x\rightarrow \infty$

I started by looking the at the exponent $\cos\sqrt{t}$, taking the derivative and setting it $0$ gives me $0,\pi^2,2^2\pi^2,3^2\pi^2,...$ My guess is to use Lapalce Method now but I do not know how.

How can I continue here or is there a simpler trick for this specific integral?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function $f(t) = \cos(\sqrt{t})$ has a maximum at $t = 0$ on the interval $[0,\pi^2/4]$, and near $t = 0$ we have

$$
\cos(\sqrt{t}) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}t + O(t^2),
$$

so this suggests the change of variables

$$
\cos(\sqrt{t}) = 1 - \frac{1}{2}u.
$$

Following this change, apply [Watson's lemma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma).

Comment: Thanks I think I got it, one last question concerning the boundaries. In case we change $\pi^2/4$ to $4\pi^2$ how does the asymptotic expansion changes? I mean we have two maxima now.

Comment: Sorry I didn't get back to you about this sooner.  I answered a similar question to that scenario [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/689307/5531) which you may find helpful.