# Laplace's Method for Integral asymptotes when g(c) = 0

Tags: asymptotics

I am using [these notes](https://www.math.unl.edu/~scohn1/8423/intasym1.pdf) as my reference, but I am running into some questions.

Say I am trying to find, for large $\lambda$
$$I(\lambda)=\int_0^{\pi/2}dxe^{-\lambda\sin^2(x)}$$
This has our maximum at $c=0$, where g(c)=0 and g'(c)$\neq$0.  So when I pull out the $e^{\lambda g(c)}$, that is just 1, so I continue to expand g(x) about x = 0, and then change the bounds from -Infinity to Infinity.
$$I(\lambda)\approx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\exp[-\lambda(x^2-x^4/3+...)]$$
To first order, this is just $\sqrt{(\pi/x)}$, but the second order diverges.

The reason this stumps me is because I can find an [exact solution](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate%5BExp%5B-a*Sin%5Bx%5D%5E2%5D%2C%7Bx%2C0%2CPi%2F2%7D%5D) that depends on $e^x$ so I am not sure where i am going wrong in computing the behavior.

Comment: Instead of $$I(\lambda)\approx\int_{-\infty}^\infty dx\exp[-\lambda(x^2-x^4/3+...)]$$ you actually have $$I(\lambda)\approx\int_{0}^\infty dx\exp[-\lambda(x^2-x^4/3+...)]$$ because of the one-sided maximum at $x=0$.

Comment: Still blows up at infinity

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood: the idea is that the series in the exponent in the expression I wrote can be truncated at any point. You are not meant to sum the series then integrate from $0$ to $\infty$. You are meant to truncate the series, say just at $x^2$, then integrate.

Comment: True.  However, I am looking for an expression good through second order, so wouldn't I need to keep that term, OR, do I expand the results, (which would be 1/sqrt(x)) to 2 terms?

Comment: To get the higher-order corrections, or even a full asymptotic expansion, you can follow the suggestion given by [Chappers](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/1476681/5531). Try setting $x = \arcsin \sqrt{y}$ in the original integral, then applying Watson's lemma.

Comment: You might like to look at these similar questions: [one](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/270628/5531), [two](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/672794/5531), and [three](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/689307/5531).

Comment: So I do the substitution to get

$$I = \int_0^1 \frac{dy e^{-\lambda y}}{2\sqrt y\sqrt{1-y}}$$

But can Watsons be used, because the g(y) blows up to infinity as I get to 0?

Comment: Ignore that last comment, I was able to work through it with Watsons lemma.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Great, glad to help. :) I suggest adding an answer to this question yourself to give the details on your calculation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that you have an endpoint maximum, and hence the integral should only be one-sided; this is the sort of case where [Watson's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Watson%27s_lemma) applies.

Answer (score 2):

You can take advantage of the symmetry of your integrand to make the maximum point an interior point: $I(\lambda)=\int_0^{\pi/2} e^{-\lambda\sin^2(x)}\,dx ={1\over 2}\int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2}e^{-\lambda\sin^2(x)}\,dx$. Laplace's Method then yields $I(\lambda)\sim \sqrt{\pi\over 4\lambda}$. This is consistent with your exact evaluation of $I(\lambda)$ and the known large-$\lambda$ asymptototics for the Bessel function $I_0$: $I_0(x)={e^x\over\sqrt{2\pi x}}+e^x\cdot O(x^{-3/2})$.

Comment: How could I solve for the coefficient on O($x^{-3/2}$)?

Comment: @yankeefan11: wolframalpha will give you the complete asymptotic expansion of $I_0(x)$ for large $x$.

Comment: Im trying to solve for myself :)

Answer (score 1):

That integral can be computed in a explicit way by using modified Bessel functions of the first kind:

$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{-\lambda\sin(x)^2}\,dx = \frac{\pi}{2}e^{-\lambda/2}\,I_0(\lambda/2) \tag{1}$$
then the asymptotic form follows from [Hankel's expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Asymptotic_forms):
$$ \int_{0}^{\pi/2} e^{-\lambda\sin(x)^2}\,dx \approx \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{4\lambda }}\left(1+\frac{1}{4\lambda}\right).\tag{2} $$

Comment: So from Hankel's expansion, do you need to know that it can be explicitly calculated first?

Comment: Well, Hankel's expansion applies to Bessel functions. If you do not know you are dealing with a Bessel function, you may still prove $(2)$ through the usual Laplace method / Watson lemma.