# How to approximate integral of $e^{x \cos \phi}$ when $x \gg 1$?

Tags: integration, approximation

Let $I(x)$ be

$I(x) = \int _{-\pi} ^\pi e^{x \cos \phi}d\phi$.

When $x \gg 1$, how to get major terms of (how to approximate) $I(x)$?

There must be the solution but I don't have any idea. In the textbook, it is said that "You can use

$\int _{-\infty} ^\infty  e^{-\alpha \psi ^2}d\psi = \sqrt{\frac{\pi}{\alpha}}$

for $\alpha > 0$ thought I don't know this is really needed. (The result is used to solve a bachelor-level physics problem. So the process may not be a quite difficult one.)

Comment: Use Laplace Method.

Comment: By looking at the plot of this function, it looks like $I(x) \sim \pi e^x$. You can understand this by noticing that for $x\gg 1$, whenever $\cos\phi$ is negative, $e^{x\cos\phi}\sim 0$, and whenever it is positive, $e^{x\cos\phi}$ is enormous.

Comment: Much thanks to both of you. I'll try with Laplace method or saddle point method.

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/672794/5531)

Answer (score 2):

Note that $$ I(x) = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{x \cos \phi}\, d\phi = e^x \cdot \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-2x \sin^2 \left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}\, d\phi.$$
As a result, we have the estimation
$$
e^x \cdot \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-2x \sin^2 \left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)}\cdot \cos\left(\frac{\phi}{2}\right)\, 
d\phi \leq I(x) \leq e^x \cdot \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{-2x \left(\frac{\phi}{\pi}\right)^2 }\, 
d\phi,
$$
which can be reduced to
$$ \frac{2e^x}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot \int_{-\pi\sqrt{x}}^{\pi\sqrt{x}}e^{-2t^2}\,dt \leq I(x) \leq \frac{\pi e^x}{\sqrt{x}}\cdot \int_{-\sqrt{x}}^{\sqrt{x}}e^{-2t^2}\,dt .$$
Thus we have 
$$ \sqrt{2\pi}\left(1 - 2e^{-2\pi^2 x}\right) \cdot \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}} \leq I(x) \leq \sqrt{\frac{\pi^3}{2}} \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}},$$
where the first inequality follows from the [Chernoff bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound).

When $x \gg 1$, we have $\displaystyle I(x) = \Theta\left(\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}\right)$.

---

Remark: 
[Laplace's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) will give
$$\lim_{x\to +\infty} \frac{I(x)}{\sqrt{2\pi} e^x\cdot x^{-1/2}} = 1.$$